# RxJS error handling

Tags: javascript, error-handling, reactive-programming, rxjs

I've got an issue with RxJS swallowing errors. So in my case I've got something like this:

```
function funcThatThrowsError(fn, ..args) {
     return fn.bind(fn, ...args);
}

function fetchItems() {
     Observable.fromPromise(
        reqwest({
            url: `${API_ROOT}${url}`,
            method,
            data,
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
    ).map(funcThatThrowsError(null, "someValue"))
}

const observableA = fechItems();
const observableB = ... ;

Observable
    .combineLatest(
        observableA,
        observableB,
        () =>  { }
    )
    .forEach(
        () => { }, // success
        (err) -> console.log(err.stack);
    )
```

So basically I'm deliberately passing a null value as the `fn` parameter which causes the `funcThatThrowsError` to throw an exception.

The problem is that the error callback is not invoked in this case. Rather RxJS will use it's own `thrower` function

```
function thrower(e) {
   throw e;
}
```

What's the best practise to deal with this scenario. I feel that there is something that I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is happening outside of the Observable. You are raising it while creating a function that you want to pass into the observable.

If you want the error handler at the end of the chain to handle it, you have to raise it *inside* of the operator chain:

```
function fetchItems() {
     Observable.fromPromise(
        request({
            url: `${API_ROOT}${url}`,
            method,
            data,
            contentType: "application/json"
        })
    ).map(funcThatThrowsError(content => throw new Error(content), "someValue"))
}
```